# How do you export .caffemodels to other applications?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

Is it possible to translate the info in a .caffemodel file such that it could be read by (for example) Matlab. That is, is there a way to write your model using something else that prototxt and import the weights trained using Caffe?

If the answer is "Nope, it's a binary file and will always remain that way", is there some documentation regarding the structure of the file so that one could extract the important information somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, `.caffemodel` consists of weights and biases.
A simple way to read weights and biases for a caffemodel given the prototxt would be to just load the network in Python and read the weights.

You can use:

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net(<prototxt-file>,<model-file>,<phase>);
```

and access the params from `net.params`

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/ES86FI-3vbY/I13VVwIBAwAJ)

Comment: I see. Is it only through that interface you can do it? Pycaffe isn't working on my unit. It can't find Google protobuf.

Comment: I believe this is the easiest way to do it. Try to research about why Pycaffe is not working (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/9Q10WkpCGxs).

Comment: By god Ghassem, you solved both my problems! You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take VGG as an example

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
net = caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
caffemodel = sys.argv[1]
with open(caffemodel, 'rb') as f:
    net.ParseFromString(f.read())
for i in net.layer:
    print i.ListFields()[0][-1]
#conv1
#relu1
#norm1
#pool1
#conv2
#relu2
#norm2
#pool2
#conv3
#relu3
#conv4
#relu4
#conv5
#relu5
#pool5
#fc6
#relu6
#drop6
#fc7
#relu7
#drop7
#fc8
#prob
```